# R drawing a graph

Tags: r, plot

I have a frame like this

- ____y : 1 2 4
- x_min : 1 2 1
- x_max : 1 5 5

[image]

How can I plot a graph like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `ggplot`:

```
require(ggplot2)

#data prep
df <- read.table(text="____y : 1 2 4
x_min : 1 2 1
x_max : 1 5 5",as.is=TRUE)

df1 <- as.data.frame(t(df[,3:5]))
colnames(df1) <- c("y","x_min","x_max")

df1
#    y x_min x_max
# V3 1     1     1
# V4 2     2     5
# V5 4     1     5

#plot
ggplot(df1,aes(x = x_min, y = y, xend = x_max, yend = y)) +
  geom_segment() +
  #added point, to show zero length lines.
  geom_point()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I want to add +1 to your answer, but I don't have enough reputation =(